# How to create column where i can only add value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named "`Category`" and another named "`Article`".
I want to have a Column in `Article` where i can add `value` from `Category` only with a `multichoice` `form`.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Foreign Keys contraint will help you achieve this. Read at : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Foreign Keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) constraint will help you achieve this.